# Facebook request doesn't wait for user input

Tags: android, facebook

I'm writing an app that can post on Facebook in the behave of the user.
the process of posting is clicking on the FB button, the next thing that's suppose to happen is that Facebook attempts to login, and if the user is already loged in, using the SSO, it creates a Facebook dialog and posts it on the users feed.

However, there's no interaction with the user, and the post is being posted on Facebook as is.

how can I prompt the regular mobile app user-interaction for publishing on Facebook?

**Code for logging into Facebook:**

```
public static final String appid = "1234567890";
public static final String[] permissions = { "publish_stream" };
Facebook facebook;

facebook.authorize(MyClass.this, permissions,
                new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // control comes here if the login was successful
            // Facebook.TOKEN is the key by which the value of
            // access token is stored in the Bundle called
            // 'values'
            Log.d("COMPLETE", "AUTH COMPLETE. VALUES: "
                                + values.size());
            Log.d("AUTH TOKEN",
                    "== " + values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
            updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK ERROR", "FB ERROR. MSG: " + e.getMessage()
                    + ", CAUSE: " + e.getCause());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "AUTH ERROR. MSG: " + e.getMessage()
                    + ", CAUSE: " + e.getCause());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("CANCELLED", "AUTH CANCELLED");
        }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult");
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Code for `publishStream()`:**

```
protected void updateStatus(String accessToken) {
    try {
        Bundle msg = new Bundle();
        msg.putString("description", this.title);
        msg.putString("link", this.link);
        msg.putString("message", description);
        msg.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", msg, "POST");
        Log.d("UPDATE RESPONSE", "" + response);
        Toast.makeText(SinglePost.this, "Posted on Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `facebook.request()` method, it will post your message silently in background. To show a dialog, you will use `facebook.dialog()` method. Your code will look like this:

```
facebook.dialog(context, "stream.publish", parameters, new SomeDialogListener());
```

Where `SomeDialogListener` is subclass of `DialogListener` and will be your callback instance to handle response from `facebook` (same as in case of your login dialog).